# Отправка уведомлений через бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Нужно, чтобы бот отправлял сообщение мне. Но я хочу, чтобы бот отправлял сообщение 'Пришлите свои требования к боту которые должен выполнить исполнитель', потом пользователь писал требования, а затем эти требования отправлялись мне.

Вот часть кода, в которой я хочу это сделать:

```
@client.message_handler(content_types = ["text"])
def telegram(message):
    if message.text == 'Telegram':
        client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Пришлите свои требования к боту которые должен выполнить исполнитель :')
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы за вас написали бота, который будет получать заказы на написание ботов? ))) Читайте [mastergroosha](https://mastergroosha.github.io/telegram-tutorial/)  и [suren](https://surik00.gitbooks.io/aiogram-lessons/content/)

Comment: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py `bot.register_next_step_handler`

Answer (score 3):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Пришлите свои требования к боту которые должен выполнить исполнитель')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start_2)


def start_2(message):
    requirement = message.text  # для наглядности, можно опустить
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ваши требования к исполнителю:\n{}'.format(requirement))
```